# How can I customize the destination of where dependencies resources are placed in an APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.3

I am looking for a way to customize where an android application places any of its dependencies resource files. These properties files are part of resource directories in jar dependencies.

I've looked at the aapt documentation's [aaptOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions.html) and [packagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html) of the [Android DSL docs](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html), but can't find any way to manipulate the destination of assets, res, resources files found in a projects dependencies.

Here's an example of the APK when viewed the APK Analyzer built into Android Studio. The blacked out names of properties files are the ones I'd like moved into assets or res folders.[image: analyzed apk example]

I'd like for them to be placed into the assets or res folders of the APK rather than in the root path of the apk.

Comment: You really shouldn't. Android runs on a specific system, changing paths could in theory break it. And what kind of use do you have for it? There's no practical use to it.

Comment: We are using commercial tools to protect our APK and they obfuscate and encrypt our APK and its contents. Some of these tools work on resource files, but only if they're in assets or res directories. They manipulate the APK, so I know changing where things is won't be an issue, just wanted to know if there was any way to do that via gradle/android.

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose where files are placed in the APK.

The structure is like that, so when the APK is unpacked on device, the Android system knows how to handle the files and where they are located.

If you could randomly move files around and into other folders, it would completely break the installation of APK files.

Comment: I'm not looking to randomly move files, I want them in specific folders. The properties files are from other libraries we've written and when the Android gradle plugin packages it I'd love to be able to customize where it puts the files, but understand it may not be possible. Also, while the structure is important it is possible to modify/change it, for example tools like Dexprotector (which we are using) do just that to the APK, so while it is not a good idea to randomly move stuff if done the right way it is possible.